# Why is NodeList inside the script is empty but it's not in the Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm doing my first steps with async-await functions and currently trying it on JSONPlaceholder site.
I've managed to fetch the data and now I want to add event listeners to every 'a' tag. The problem is as described in the title: the results of getElementByClassName or querySelectorAll are empty in the script but it works in the browser! I suppose my attempts to access those elements run before async function end. If so how should it be done?

I've tried: putting the script at the very end of the html body (thinking it's going to run after evrything else is loaded); at the end of async function, but that just doesn't work.

The script which I'm trying to get working right now is simple (file's name's 'posts.js'): *post-item is is a class name for a tag

```
let catalogItems = document.querySelector('[data-catalog-items]');
let postItems = [...catalogItems.getElementsByClassName('post-item')];
console.log(postItems);
```

My async function:

```
class HTTPResponseError extends Error {
    constructor(response) {
        super(`HTTP Error Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
        this.response = response;
    }
}

const getPostItems = async ({limit, page}) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=${limit}&_page=${page}`);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new HTTPResponseError(response);
        }
        const total = +response.headers.get('x-total-count');
        const items = await response.json();
        return {items, total};
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what the two blocks of code you posted have to do with each other. They look completely unrelated.

Comment: If you do the `let o = document.querySelector('[data-catalog-items]');` on the top level of a `<script>` block, in the `<head>`, the document simply does not exist that point. These kind of things should go into an event handler of [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event), or a simple [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: There is no indication that after `getPostItems()` there would be any new DOM elements which `document.querySelector('[data-catalog-items]')` and/or `o.getElementsByClassName('post-item')` would be able to find. So you can wait for it, bt seems unlikely this will change anything about the behaviour.

Comment: In the browser when the the code is done fetching data and the page is built I can retrieve what I need: the post-items. But It's not happening inside my code wherever I put those three lines. Is it possible to ensure that first short lines of code (even if I put them in separate file) will be executed exactly after all async code is executed?

Comment: Yes, you can put them in the block of code after the `await`. (Assuming you also do the work to extend the DOM there.)

Comment: You're not showing how your elements are being created in reaction to getPostItems(). However, you need to wait for them to be created before you can query them. Don't use setTimeout, as that does not guarantee they will be ready. await getPostItems() and then query the DOM.

Comment: I agree with you about setTimeout approach, it's not possible to predict the correct timeout value. Is it possible to wrap getPostItems with another(async?) function? The one which will handle query to DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to **postItems** after you've completed the query for sure.

Asynchronous functions always return promises.

```
getPostItems.then((data) => {
  // Element rendering logic ...
  console.log(postItems)
})
```

It's a little unclear on the two pieces of code, but I hope I got it right.

Answer (score -2):

If you use this script at the beginning of a script.js file: I have the same problem, and I have recover like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {/*code here*/},1)
```

It's not the best solution, but it works. I think we can do a thing with onload, but I didn't try.

You can try too with:

```
window.onload = function(event) {/*code here*/}
```

The bug is here because the page isn't loaded, and the JavaScript can't access DOM if it isn't loaded.

It's for that that we say that when Window in loaded, we can select items in the DOM and continue the script

Comment: I checked, and we can do this thing too: ```window.onload = function(event) {/*code here*/}```.Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: It worked (with timeout of 1000 ms), thank you. But now I couldn't help but wonder: is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Yeah: ```window.onload = function(event) {/*code here*/}```

Comment: And don't forgot to put this thread as "resolved"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).